# Slider to stop moving out of screen when the page is zoomed in mobile sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I am adding a QapTcha pluggin into my website, I am using jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js.
However, when I zoom into a page from a mobile site and I drag my slider left, it moves out of the bar, which it isn't supposed to do. I have attached pictures to give an idea of whats going on.

[image: As you can see when the page is loaded the scroll bar that says "Scroll right" is situated perfectly in the bar and it doesnt move off it onto the left]

[image: When you swipe right it still works fine stays in the bar]

[image: the problem occurs when you zoom into the page and you swipe the scroll bar it moves left out of the page]

The problem occurs when you zoom into the page and you swipe the scroll bar it moves left out of the page as you can see in the 3rd image. This is my code:

```
 Slider.draggable({

                containment: bgSlider,
                axis: 'x',
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.position.left > 123) {
                        Slider.draggable('disable').css('cursor', 'default');
                        inputQapTcha.val("");
                        TxtStatus.css({ color: '#307F1F' }).text(opts.txtUnlock);
                        Icons.css('background-position', '-16px 0');
                        //form.find('input[type=\'submit\']').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $(opts.buttonLock).removeAttr('disabled');
                        ///Show a fornm
                        if ($(opts.buttonLock).attr("show")) {
                            $($(opts.buttonLock).attr("show")).css("display", "block");
                            $("#QapTcha").fadeOut(500);
                        }
                        else if (opts.buttonLock == 'input[name="SendMail"]') {
                            $(opts.buttonLock).bind("click", function () {
                                AuroraJS.Modules.SendMail(this);
                            });
                        }
                        else if (opts.buttonFunc != "") {
                            $(opts.buttonLock).bind("click", function () {
                                opts.buttonFunc();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

How I can prevent it from moving out of the bar when the page is zoomed into?

Comment: You have to write class css using mediaquery and adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Ananta Prasad How does "media queries" solve a manual zoom issue?

Comment: css has that power to solve @seahor

Answer (score 0):

A link to a working example of the issue would help in resolving the issue.

From as far I can see, the only thing I could think of is that something might go wrong with positioning. You could try resolving this by adding `position: relative;` to the slider container.

Comment: i already have that in my css ,and it still does the above.its just not staying in the containment and i have no idea why. the issue only appears on touch screen sites,on a normal desktop it works fine

Comment: Any chance you can post a link to a site with the issue?